# Planning with Numerical Values and PROLOG

Tags: prolog, planning

I am trying to use this Planner [https://www.cs.unm.edu/~luger/ai-final/code/PROLOG.planner.html](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Eluger/ai-final/code/PROLOG.planner.html) .

I want to search a space with a numerical value. Below you can see my implementation of sum that is tested and seems to work. Then there are my two moves, plus and minus, where I delete the `value(X)` and add `value(Y)` where `Y` is `X +- 1` respectively.

If I now consult the planner (last statement with go), I do not get the expected result of `plus()` but instead `false` as the planner does not find a way from `value(2)` to `value(3)`.

```
sum(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X+Y.

move(plus(), [value(X)], [del(value(X)), sum(X,1,Y) , add(value(Y))]).
move(minus(), [value(X)], [del(value(X)), sum(X,-1,Y) , add(value(Y))]).

go([value(2)], [value(3)]).
```

Answer (score 0):

The predicate `move(Action, Preconditions, Effects)` describes the changes caused by the execution of `Action` in a state where the conditions established in list `Preconditions` hold. In a fact for this predicate, the list `Effects` must consist only of terms of the form `add(Fluent)` and `del(Fluent)`. So, I think the correct definition of actions `plus` and `minus` should be as follows:

```
move(plus,  [value(X)], [del(value(X)), add(value(Y))]) :- Y is X + 1.
move(minus, [value(X)], [del(value(X)), add(value(Y))]) :- Y is X - 1.
```